# A question about a claim from "Riemannian Geometry" by Petersen

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-functions

Petersen says the following on pg 13 of "Riemannian Geometry" by Petersen:

> If $\frac{\psi^2-1}{t^2}$ is a smooth function of $t$ at $t=0$, then $\psi^{(1)}=\psi^{(3)}=\dots=\psi^{(odd)}=0$

I don't understand this claim. What if $\psi=(1+t^2+t^3)$? The function $\frac{\psi^2-1}{t^2}$ still seems to be smooth, and some odd derivatives of $\psi$ are non-zero.

Comment: It looks unlikely ... is there anything else that Petersen assumes about $\psi$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown- No. He just assumes $\psi$ is smooth analytic